# Case is not decrementing Entitlement's Remaining Time after Closed in Dynamics 365

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

We are encountering a problem in decrementing the field Remaining Time of Entitlement entity. It is not decrementing if Decrease Remaining On is set to Case Resolution.

[image: Case Resolution for Decrease Remaining On]

However, if it is set to Case Creation, it is decrementing.

[image: Case Creation for Decrease Remaining On]

Upon checking the Incident.StateCode (Case's Status Column**)**, it's values are Active, Closed, and Cancelled instead of Active, Resolved, and Cancelled. Does this affect the Remaining Time the reason it is not decrementing if the Decrease Remaining On is set to Case Resolution? If yes, how can I change this? The options are not enabled.

[image: Incident.StateCode Option Value]

If no, are there any ways I can check why this is happening?

By the way, this project was only passed to us as the developers of this project resigned already.

We are hoping someone could help us sort this problem out.

Thank you.